# Definition file best practices for npm package exporting constructor

Tags: typescript

I published a **npm package** ([rotating-file-stream](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rotating-file-stream)) which exports directly the *constructor* of my class:

```
function RotatingFileStream(filename, options) { ... }

module.exports = RotatingFileStream;
```

Somebody is asking me for adding a **TypeScript** *definition file*, but unfortunately I don't know **TypeScript**.

Considering that my class inherits **fs.WriteStream**, with the help from some contributors, I arrived to following *definition file*:

```
import { WriteStream } from "fs";

interface RfsOptions {
  compress?: string | Function | boolean
  highWaterMark?: number
  ...
}

export default function (fileName: string | Function, options: RfsOptions): WriteStream;
```

but I read somewhere that exporting a *default function* is not a good idea.

Can you suggest me how to change my **package** and/or my *definition file* in order to achieve following targets?

1. Don't change the **package** *interface* (due it already has some download)
2. To have a *definition file* which follows **TypeScript** best practices.

**Edit:** Now the package is completely rewritten in TypeScript; I opted to change major version due to removing the default export have been a breaking change.

Comment: Where did you read that default-exporting a function is a bad idea?  Many npm packages do it.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/iccicci/rotating-file-stream/issues/29) I did, I'm trying to solve a reported issue. Apart from this, do you think my _definition file_ is fine or something in it can be done better? Thank you

Comment: I see.  A named export may have been preferable for [these reasons](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html), but it is too late now: removing the export assignment would break the package interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your package has an *export assignment* (a function is assigned to `module.exports`: a CommonJS/Node-specific concept) but your declaration file has an ES6 *default export*.  The difference matters when the `esModuleInterop` compiler option is disabled, which I'm guessing is the case for the reporter of [the bug](https://github.com/iccicci/rotating-file-stream/issues/29).  To make the declaration file more accurately match the package, you could use an export assignment there:

```
function RotatingFileStream(fileName: string | Function, options: RfsOptions): WriteStream;
export = RotatingFileStream;
```

Hopefully that will fix the reporter's problem.